# Interface for DjangoFilterConnectionField

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphql, graphene-django

I have two classes

```
class RegisteredUser(graphene.ObjectType):
  
   class Meta:
    interfaces = (BaseClient, )
  
  name = graphene.String() 
  group = graphene.String()
  policy = graphene.Int()
  event = graphene_django.filter.DjangoFilterConnectionField(AuthEvent, max_limit=15)
```

Then I also have another class for users that have not signed up

```
class NonRegisteredUser(graphene.ObjectType):
  
   class Meta:
    interfaces = (BaseClient, )

  name = graphene.String() 
  source = graphene.Int()
  event = graphene_django.filter.DjangoFilterConnectionField(NonRegisteredEvent, max_limit=15)
```

And finally we have BaseClient class which is the common interface for both of the above classes

```
class BaseClient(graphene.Interface):

    name = graphene.String()
    event = graphene_django.filter.DjangoFilterConnectionField('NotSureWhatToAdd', max_limit=15)
    @classmethod
    def resolve_type(cls, instance, info):
        if instance.type == 'RegisteredUser':
            return RegisteredUser
        
        return NonRegisteredUser
```

Now everything works fine if I query "name" field but not sure how do I make 'events' field work since both have different DjangoFilterConnectionField.

Answer (score 0):

Hey im not certain about this because I haven't faced this myself. But since there are no answers here Im just gonna throw this out there. I dont think that you need things that are different in the base interface. And i dont think you need things that are in common in the sub object types.

So, what this means is that you can probably delete

```py
 events = graphene_django.filter.DjangoFilterConnectionField('NotSureWhatToAdd', max_limit=15)
```

in the `BaseClient`

and you can also probably delete `name = graphene.String()` from the two subclasses.

Also Im not sure if this is intentional but you seem to be using plural `events` in the base and singular `event` in the objectType classes

Comment: Thanks @rymanso.
yeah that was a typo , I meant to use 'event' instead of 'events'.

Comment: if I remove 'event' from the 'Baseclient' I would no longer be able to retrieve event data.

Based on the client id , I am deciding whether to return 'RegisteredUser' or 'NonRegisteredUser' data which works fine as long as django connection field is not present. Unfortunately I am restricted from modifying any thing in class RegisteredUser